Undefined namespace. 'CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls' that could not be found. WINUI3
i am new to WinUI3.
I am using this Windows Community Toolkit Gallery, which has great samples and want to implement a GridSplitter.
I see that I need
namespace
CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls
NuGet Packages
CommunityToolkit.Uwp.Controls.Sizers
CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls.Sizers

I have installed both in NuGet package manager
CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls.Sizers 8.1.240916

and
CommunityToolkit.Uwp.Controls.Sizers 8.1.240916

In the XAML-page, i have implemented it via     xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls"
as given in example in Windows Community Toolkit Gallery, but I always get the error
Undefined namespace. The 'using' URI refers to a namespace 'CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls' that could not be found.

What can I do?

Since it seems that this is a WinUI 3 app, you don't need to install:
CommunityToolkit.Uwp.Controls.Sizers

Now to fix the error, open your project file (*.csproj) and edit your target versions to 22621.
<TargetFramework>net9.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>
<WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.22621.38</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>

You can find about this in the release notes.
